# phpmyadmin connecting to database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website that connects to a database and retrieves page content and all works fine. However, I then use the same database connection to connect to and retrieve user details for logging in to my site (2 tables but both in same database). However, I get the following error message when doing this.

```
Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Comment: Btw, mysql is deprecated and will be removed. Instead use mysqli. Documentation -> http://bg2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint is in "using password NO"  There is no password being sent - in fact it is only using username@localhost as the username so it looks like you don't have your credentials configured properly.

Check config.inc.php - http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Configuration_storage

Comment: There is a password being sent in actual fact and the credentials are set-up as they successfully retrieve the page content

Comment: So you say, but the error tells us something else.  Perhaps there is another place it is attempting to connect.

Comment: I simply pass in the original connection as an argument to the function I have that retrieves login details. Don't see why it shouldn't connect second time round

Answer (score 0):

Well it's says that your password is not correct and that you haven't gained access. Can you please upload a code here ? if you're using **localhost**, then the username should be **root** .. try to change it and leave the password field empty for now.

Comment: For whatever reason making a second connection to the same database has enabled me to get the login details aswell so problem solved but no idea why using the original did not work

Comment: sometimes it happens :/ .. maybe you can try to delete the older one and leave just one there :P